# If one value exists then remove another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, group-by, remove-if

I'm stuck in my query on how to remove or rather skip a post if another one exists.

[image]

This is my table.

if **L_ID** column have value **821** AND **201** for the same **P_ID** then "remove" or don´t use 201 and `sum()` then time

This would make P_ID 80 and 946 only have 2 rows.

This is probably easier than I think but I'm stuck.

Comment: sum what?, sum all rows after remove or sum group by?

Comment: sum Time after the remove of 201 and then Group by p_id,Lid and date

Comment: Try my code in answer below. Hope it help

Comment: Hi, if one of these answers could help you to solve your problem, you should vote helpful answers up and mark the most helpful as accepted. Thx!

Comment: Hi yes of course you code helped a lot thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #YourTable(P_ID INT, L_ID INT, [Date] Date, [Time] DECIMAL(6,2));
INSERT INTO #YourTable VALUES
 (80,201,{d'2015-08-01'},24.0)
,(80,821,{d'2015-08-01'},24.0)
,(80,822,{d'2015-08-01'},32.0)
,(946,201,{d'2015-08-01'},16.0)
,(946,821,{d'2015-08-01'},16.0)
,(946,819,{d'2015-08-01'},6.65)
,(6758,201,{d'2015-08-01'},7.25)
,(6758,200,{d'2015-08-01'},7.25)
;

--Test output
SELECT * FROM #YourTable;

--Set the SUMs in those lines with L_ID=821
UPDATE #YourTable SET [Time]=(SELECT SUM(x.[Time]) 
                              FROM #YourTable AS x 
                              WHERE x.P_ID =#YourTable.[P_ID] 
                                    AND x.L_ID IN (821,201))
WHERE #YourTable.L_ID=821

--Delete the rows with L_ID=201 if there is one with 821 too
DELETE FROM #YourTable 
WHERE L_ID = 201 AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #YourTable AS x 
                            WHERE x.P_ID = #YourTable.P_ID AND x.L_ID =821 ) --The ID was wrong here, sorry...

--Test output
SELECT * FROM #YourTable;

--Clean up
DROP TABLE #YourTable;
```

Result:

```
P_ID    L_ID    Date        Time
80      821    2015-08-01   48.00
80      822    2015-08-01   32.00
946     821    2015-08-01   32.00
946     819    2015-08-01   6.65
6758    201    2015-08-01   7.25
6758    200    2015-08-01   7.25
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SELECT *,
   SUM(Time) OVER(PARTITION BY P_ID, L_ID, Date) AS 'Sum'
FROM Your_Table
WHERE L_ID <> 201
   AND P_ID NOT IN (
      SELECT E1.P_ID
      FROM Your_Table E1
         INNER JOIN Your_Table E2
            ON E1.P_ID = E2.P_ID
      WHERE E1.L_ID = 821 AND E2.L_ID = 201)
```